# Automatic cast reflection

Tags: casting

how can I make an automatic cast without specifying the type of the variable:

```
TypaA a = (TypeA) refA;
```

I do not want to write `TypeA` hard, instead I want to deduce in terms of the reference `refA`.

In my opinion, I think I should work with the reflection!

Comment: A language tag would probably help here.

Answer (score 1):

You can automatically cast to base classes, so if B derives from A you can have A a = someB;

Explicit casts tell the compiler "yes, I meant to write this", static typing is your friend.

Comment: @arshajii whatever language it is it's statically typed. I can't think of one that doesn't work like this. TypeA is not a fundamental type, so we can assume it's object orientated, thus inheritance, thus implict casts. I'm guessing Java, or C++ (no *s). this is an aspect of object orientated programming, not a language.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I guess it's somewhat language independent at this point.

Comment: @arshajii I did what I could with the one line :P It's still a bad question which is why I put "static typing is your friend. Anyway nice meeting you.